# Font size issue in Nexus 5

Tags: android

I am giving font size as **12sp** in **dimens.xml** of **/res/values** folder for textview.

When I tried this font on Nexus 5 device (which falls in XXHDPI bucket), I got text size as **36**. Then I tried created new **dimens.xml** in **/res/values-xxhdpi** folder with same **12sp** as text size. Still it is giving me font size as **36**.

I want to keep font size as **12sp** only. What could be the possible reason of this?

Note that I am adding TextView programmtically and setting it's size by

```
context.getResources().getDimension(
            R.dimen.font_size)
```

Comment: in `xxhdpi` every `1sp` is equal with `3px` then when you set `12sp` size in your device must be `36px`. and if you test on multi device you get different number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1sp = 3px` on an `XXHDPI` device. You are using the same `sp` value in all of your `dimens.xml`, so on an `MDPI` device you have `12sp = 12px`, but on the Nexus you have `12sp = 36px`.

Set the text size to `4sp` for the Nexus if you want it exactly the same size as on an `MDPI` device.

You may just as well use a single `dimens.xml` and use `px` as the units instead of `sp` so the font size is not scaled.